# Regex consume a character if it matches, but not otherwise

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write a regex expression which will capture all instances of the '@' character, *except* when two such characters appear in succession (essentially, an escape sequence).  For example:

`abd@ajk`: `@` should be matched

`abd@@ajk`: No matches

`abd@@@ajk`: The *final* `@` should match.

`abd@@@@ajk`: No matches

This almost works with the negative lookahead expression `@(?!@)`, except that because the second `@` is not consumed, the last of two `@` symbols will still be matched.  What I think I want to do is to lookahead for an `@` but consume the character if it is there; otherwise, do not consume it.  Is this possible?

Edit: I'm using Javascript which unfortunately rules out several good approaches :(

Comment: Are you replacing or matching? What is the language, BTW?

Comment: Try [`(?<!@)(?:@@)*\K@(?!@)`](https://regex101.com/r/S6ys0i/1)

Comment: another solution `@@(*SKIP)(?!)|@`

Comment: A Java workaround would be `(?<=(?<!@)(?:@@){0,999})@(?!@)`

Comment: If you plan to "escape" unescaped `@`, you may use [`(?<!@)((?:@@)*)@(?!@)` and replace with `$1@@`](https://regex101.com/r/S6ys0i/4).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm actually splitting the string on these characters.  Your solution is great, except it doesn't work in Javascript - thanks though!

Comment: @revo this works in Javascript - if you want to add it as an answer I will accept it :)  Also, could you explain the `{0,999}` part?  Will it restrict the number of matches in some way?

Comment: Do you need [`s.match(/(?:[^@]|@@)+/g)`](https://regex101.com/r/S6ys0i/5)? See https://jsfiddle.net/nznbdn66/1/

Comment: Oh my, JS regexp in Chrome supports unlimited width lookbehinds :)

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, to split strings at an unescaped `@`, you may actually *match* chunks of text that is either `@@` (an escaped `@`) and any chars other than `@`:

```js
var strs = ['abd@ajk','abd@@ajk','abd@@@ajk','abd@@@@ajk'];
var rx = /(?:[^@]|@@)+/g;
for (var s of strs) {
 console.log(s, "=>", s.match(rx))
}
```

The regex is

```
/(?:[^@]|@@)+/g
```

See [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/S6ys0i/5)

**Details**

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group that matches either of the 2 alternatives:

  - [^@]`- any char other than`@`
  - `|` - or
  - `@@` - 2 `@`s
- `)+` - repeat matching 1 or more times.

The `g` modifier finds all matching occurrences inside the input string.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't tag a programming language to your question here is my 2 cents for Java:

```
(?<=(?<!@)(?:@@){0,999})@(?!@)
```

Java doesn't support infinite lookbehinds but bounded so here I explicitly specified max of even occurrences of `@`: `999`.

### JavsScript

Lookbehinds in JavaScript are not implemented and supported by many browsers yet. If you are trying to do this in JS then this would be your working solution:

#### Method 1

```
((?:[^@]*(?:@@)+[^@]*)+)|@
```

- `(?:[^@]*(?:@@)+[^@]*)+` Match `@@` occurrences and all its leading / trailing characters
- `|@` Or a single `@`

JS Code:

```
str.split(/((?:[^@]*(?:@@)+[^@]*)+)|@/).filter(Boolean);
```

#### Method 2 (Recommended)

Or if you don't have problem with using `match()` this is much more cleaner and of course faster:

```
(?:[^@]*(?:@@)+[^@]*)+|[^@]+
```

JS Code:

```js
console.log(
  "aaaa@@@@@@@bbb@aa@@@cccc@@ddddd@".match(/(?:[^@]*(?:@@)+[^@]*)+|[^@]+/g)
);
```